# Can I use functions as type in redux actions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have started to work with react + redux recently, and I wonder how I can reduce boilerplate code when I create actions and action creators. 
What if we describe action not as string, but as function, which return an action?
Let me explain.
By redux guides we can create actions like this

```
const CONTRACTS_LOAD_STARTED = 'CONTRACTS_LOAD_STARTED';
```

Actually, I prefer define actions as map

```
export const ContractsActions = {
    CONTRACTS_LOAD_STARTED: 'CONTRACTS_LOAD_STARTED',
    CONTRACTS_LOAD_OK: 'CONTRACTS_LOAD_OK',
    CONTRACTS_LOAD_ERROR: 'CONTRACTS_LOAD_ERROR'
};
```

And then we write action creator

```
export function billsLoadStarted() {
    return {
        type: BillsActions.BILLS_LOAD_STARTED
    }
}
```

And then we use action creator to dispatch action and catch it in reducer.

But what if we define action as function which create an action?

```
export const BillsActions = {
    BILLS_LOAD_STARTED: () => {
        return {
            type: BillsActions.BILLS_LOAD_STARTED
        }
    }
};
```

We can dispatch it

```
dispatch(BillsActions.BILLS_LOAD_STARTED());
```

We can catch it in reducer

```
export function billsReducer(state, action) {

    if (typeof state === 'undefined') {
        return initState;
    }

    const response = action.response;
    switch (action.type) {
        case BillsActions.BILLS_LOAD_STARTED:
            return {
                bills: [],
                isLoading: true,
                error: []
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And we get less code to write.

What can be wrong in this way of defining actions?

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/faq/Actions.md#actions-string-constants

Comment: Functions are serializable, aren't they?